# issuing or issuance

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct:

> Employer's **issuing** a variation to the contract...
>
> Employer's **issuance** a variation to the contract...

Comment: Btw: "issuence" (sic) misspelled in question title.

Answer (score 1):

The statement with "issuing" is grammatically correct;

> Employer's issuing a variation to the contract...

Those dots in the end, as I assume are more than two, mean that there is a continue to your sentence. Notice that "issuing" is a gerund, which is a noun here, and it's a 'belonging' of  "employer". So we can imagine that the meaning of the phrase is as following:

> An employer has issued a variation to the contract.

It's as if you wanted all of the sentence above to be the **subject** of a new sentence, because it was needed. How? The "employer" itself wouldn't be an appropriate noun (neither would "issuance") because the sentence is talking about *a special activity* that the employer has done.

> Employer's issuance a variation to the contract...

This is most likely to be a heading for a newspaper article, if it was a full and separate sentence by itself. However, now that you mention it's supposed to be the subject of one sentence, it's grammatically wrong, since it's missing a [preposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition).

> ...issuance a variation...

As you know, noun phrases in a sentence should be connected to each other in some way. (Sometimes we aren't allowed to add anything, but the void itself becomes a connection.) Here, that connection hasn't been set up, and as Brian says, we needed something like an "of" to match the elements in the subject.

In the first one, the connection is set up! As I mentioned, its meaning can be fit into another whole statement. Therefore, in the new statement, "a variation" is an object relating to the transitive verb "issue".

I hope that's clear enough. If it wasn't please inform me.

Comment: To fix the second fragment:   "...The employer's issuance OF a variance FROM   (or a variation in) the contract..."

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I considered his second phrase as a whole sentence since there were no "etc" signs. What you say *is* true but only if we think of the second one as another incomplete statement.

Comment: Dear @MARamezani thank you very much for the explanations. actually I should have written the full sentences in my question. they are as follows; 1-the Employer's issuance a variation to the contract has changed the circumstances in the project. 2-the employer's issuing a variation to the contract has changed the circumstance in the project.

Comment: @Oguz just as I explained above a gerund here is a noun, so in your Q option 2 is correct. "Issuance" in this case can't be the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Both original examples are incomplete, as neither had a verb. The subsequently offered "complete " sentences were given in reversed order, so not sure what is meant now by first or second. However, in the one that uses  "issuance", that IS the subject of the sentence!  Or rather, the corrected noun phrase as I offered: "The Employer's issuance of a variation in the contract"  is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, the question Oguz asks is whether "...issuance a variation..." can be correct as a subject or not. Your offer is *correct*, but this isn't about correcting the wrong one, but about choosing the right one. Feel free to answer if you think more useful info can be provided. :D

Comment: @MARamezani Okay, so we agree that the one with "issuing" is correct. We only disagree on how to fix the one with "issuance". I suggest that your proposed fix changes the meaning, whereas mine does not.